# Sending unicode from JQuery ajax function to php results in question marks

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, unicode

Sending Unicode values from an html form (using JQuery ajax to PHP) results in question marks. The value is send using `$.ajax` and `data = form.serialize()`.  The data looks like this before sending it to PHP `%d9%86%D9%83` and so on. I tried to encode the value in the PHP side using many functions, but no luck.

I can provide a sample link if any one can help.

Thanks
Zib Nimer

Comment: console.log() the data before you send it to ajax. Maybe you send some space or some other character that is then encoded this way.

Comment: Are you doing any htaccess rewriting?

Comment: `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8<br/>


RewriteEngine On<br/>


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br/>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br/>

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)<br/>


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your PHP file saved as Encode UTF-8?
2. Try using encodeURIComponent(fld.val()) and send it by itself and see what you get:- instead of serialize(), just to test.

Comment: Yes, I tried..  The code works well in my PC. However, when I move to my VPS, it does not.  You think this is a PHP configuration issue?